# C++ std::ifstream std::ios::in versus std::ios::in | std::ios::binary, why do I get junk data?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm curious when I call `read` on an `std::ifstream` object, why I get junk data if I open the file as `std::ios::in`, whereas I don't get junk data with `std::ios::in | std::ios::binary`?

I included screenshots of some messy code I've been trying stuff out with. I'm just confused why I get junk data with the first picture, when the second picture produces the correct data with the `std::ios::binary` flag set.

Junk data, but correct file length:
[image: Junk data, but correct file length]

No junk data, same file length:
[image: No junk data, same file length]

Comment: I'm more curious why the self-reported indexing in your loops starts reporting `last_line` at index `12` in the first example, while your second doesn't start until `16`. Almost as curious as I am for what was reported *prior* to both of those, (0..11) for the first sample, (0..15) for the second , which you inconveniently omitted from your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In text mode, certain characters may be transformed.

On [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c), it says this about binary vs. text mode for files:

> Data read in from a text stream is guaranteed to compare equal to the
>   data that were earlier written out to that stream only if all of the
>   following is true:
>
> - the data consist only of printing characters and the control
>     characters \t and \n (in particular, on Windows OS, the
>     character '\0x1A' terminates input)
> - no \n is immediately preceded by a space character (space
>     characters that are written out immediately
>     before a \n may disappear when read)
> - the last character is \n

At a guess I would say that some of the characters in your input file do not obey these rules.

Answer (score 0):

In text mode, file positions *aren't the number of bytes you can read*.

So when you seek to the end, and see the file position is 24, that doesn't mean you can read 24 bytes. In fact you only read 20 bytes, but your loop ran 24 times, printing the 20 read bytes and another 4 garbage bytes from whatever was already in memory.

To find out the actual number of bytes that were read, you can call `file_data.gcount()` after calling `file_data.read`.